# Convertir un number a string el valor dentro de una clase

Tags: javascript, typescript

tengo el siguiente problema, tengo una clase en un archivo .ts el cual almaceno en esa variable de tipo any ya que tengo un formulario dinamico.
El detalle es que almaceno en ese valores numericos y quiero convertirlos en string. intente ponerlo con la funicon de Number(cp) pero me marca error en el documento.

```html
export class InformacionProyectoInstitucion
        cp.: any
        programa_educativo: any
```

Este lo recibo en una variable importando la clase a mi componente y esto previamente lo extraigo del html del form y la variable informacion_Proyecto:

Donde tengo problemas es en el campo de codigo postal ya que deberia enviarlo como string en el json pero yo lo tengo numerico por cuestiones de diseño que me pidieron.

```js
import { InformacionProyectoInstitucion } from 'src/app/api/apis_generales/modelos_instituciones/informacionProyectoInstitucion';

AddNuevoAsesor() {
    this.informacionContacto = new InformacionContactoInstitucion();
    this.informacion_Contacto.push(this.informacionContacto);
  }

 informacion_Proyecto = [];
 
 if(this.informacion_Proyecto.length){
      for (let proyecto of this.informacion_Proyecto) {
        this.apisProyectosService.createProyecto(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(proyecto))).subscribe({
          next: (v) =>{
            if(v != null ){
              this.refreshTable();
              this.messageService.add({severity: 'success', summary: 'Completado', detail: 'Proyecto creado correctamente.', life: 3000});
            }else{
              this.messageService.add({severity: 'error', summary: 'Error', detail: 'Error proyecto no se pudo crear.', life: 3000});
            }
          },
          error: (e) =>{
            this.messageService.add({severity: 'error', summary: 'Error', detail: 'Error al guarda el proyecto', life: 3000});
            console.error(e);
          }, 
          complete: () => console.info('complete') 
        });
      }
    }
```

```html
    <button pButton pRipple pTooltip="Agregar nuevo proyecto" tooltipPosition="bottom" (click)="AddNuevoProyecto()"></button>

    <section class="container border mb-1" *ngFor="let proyecto of informacion_Proyecto; let i = index;">
                        <div class="col-12 relative" style="top: 45px; right: 0;">
                        </div>
                        <p-fieldset legend="Propuesta de proyecto ({{i + 1}})" [toggleable]="true" [transitionOptions]="'15ms'">
<input pInputText type="number" placeholder="Código postal" [(ngModel)]="proyecto.cp" pattern="/^-?\d+\.?\d*$/" onKeyPress="if(this.value.length==5) return false;"/>
<p-multiSelect 
                                    [options]="programaeducativo" 
                                    optionLabel="nombre" 
                                    optionValue="id"
                                    display="chip"
                                    appendTo="body"
                                    defaultLabel="Seleciona programa educativo" 
                                    [(ngModel)]="proyecto.programa_educativo">
                                </p-multiSelect>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo resolví de la siguiente manera después de la iteración del for:

Bueno prácticamente lo que hago es iterar esa parte del for donde asigno mi variable, declaro otra variable y solo recurro al parámetro que requiero convertir y y lo cambio con la función toString y listo.

```js
for (let proyecto of this.informacion_Proyecto) {
              let cp1 = proyecto.cp;
              proyecto.cp = cp1 > 0 ? cp1.toString() : ''; 
}
```

Espero sea de ayuda, para alguien más, saludos.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo funciona este código. Ten en cuenta que tal vez para ti sea claro lo que hace, pero para otros que lleguen a tener un problema similar no sea así. Luego, no olvides aceptar tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.

Comment: Si amigo ahora lo hago, y perdon si he querido aceptar mi pregunta pero me decia que podria hacerlo despues de 2 dias de haberlo publicado, ahorita que intenete me dice que hasta mañana puedo hacerlo.

Comment: Lo sé, es nada más un recordatorio. Todos moderamos el sitio aquí :) Tu respuesta [apareció](/review/first-answers/361226) en la cola de _Primeras Respuestas_.